# Database not updating

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite

I am working with database.When i am updating my fields for the first time database is updating.But when i try to update for the next time its not updating but it showing database is updating.Can i know where the problem is.Thanks!

```
-(void) updateData {

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    details = [updateArray objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *destinationPath = [self getDestinationPath];

    const char *dbpath = [destinationPath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE BirthdayRemainderList SET FirstName=\"%@\", LastName=\"%@\",Dob=\"%@\",Address=\"%@\",City=\"%@\",State=\"%@\",Email=\"%@\",Phone=\"%@\" WHERE ids=%@",details.firstNameString,details.lastNameString,details.dobString,details.addressString,details.cityString,details.stateString,details.emailString,details.PhoneString,details.ids];

        const char *insert_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"Row updated");

        } 

        else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to update row");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }

}
```

My Update Code goes here

```
-(IBAction) update
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    savedData = [[DetailsClass alloc] init];

    savedData.firstNameString = firstName.text;
    savedData.lastNameString = lastName.text;
    NSLog(@"last name is %@",savedData.lastNameString);
    savedData.dobString = dob.text;
    savedData.addressString = address.text;
    savedData.cityString = city.text ;
    NSLog(@"Changed city value is %@",savedData.cityString);
    savedData.stateString = state.text;
    savedData.emailString = email.text;
    NSLog(@"Changes state value is %@",savedData.emailString);
    savedData.PhoneString =  phone.text;
    NSLog(@"Phone no is %@",savedData.PhoneString);
    savedData.ids = idString;
    NSLog(@"details in id %@",savedData.ids);
    [delegate.updateArray addObject:savedData];
    [delegate updateData];

}
```

Will this make any mistake
If we use two different arrays for saving and updating it will make any difference?

Let me know where the Problem is.Thanks!

Comment: do you have an instance of that db opened somewhere else as well.. may be like sqlite dbmanager

Comment: No...i dint opened any instance.

Answer (score 1):

Add sqlite error message to get more insight of the real problem.

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Row updated");

    } 

    else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to update row %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
```

If sql db is busy somehow it would happen. Make sure you close the db if you have opened in some where else like firefox's addon.

Comment: :Thanks.But whats happening is for the first time what ever changes i made its getting updated and from 2nd time onwards my Row is updating but when i check the fields they are not updating.U given Some change for Fail condition,But my row is getting updated. What i need to do? Add there is no instance is running. I closed all instances but still the same

Comment: Copy the consrtucted query. I mean NSLog(@"%@",updateSQL). And try running the query in some sqlite manger directly and see if it is updating.

Comment: I tried sqlite manager what i have.Theres no change in that too

Comment: Your sqlite is busy for sure. do a rollback manually. and try updating it. Hope you tried in manager  after quitting your simulator and stopped the process in xcode.

Comment: Yes. I tried it and i restarted my Sys and i reseted my simulator too... but no change..